# What are the contents of a language pack?

Tags: locale, language-support, internationalization

I tried to install language-pack-fr in my Ubundu machine. It worked - but I am not clear what are things that get installed as part of the language pack.

In general , the language pack contains only fonts for the new language ? Or, what are the other contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `language-pack-*` packages contain translations for the user interfaces of the various applications found in Ubuntu, mostly in the form of [gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) message catalogues.

If you configure your user account to use a locale covered by the language pack, the user interface should then be displayed in that language when you next log in (few applications support changing their UI language while they are running).

In most cases, you wouldn't install the `language-pack-*` packages directly, but instead install the corresponding `language-support-*` package, which will give you other resources used by the language (e.g. spell checking dictionaries).

If you want to change the language settings of your Ubuntu system, the easiest method is with the `Language Support` control panel found under `System Settings`.